# Problem with write serial output via Button Clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port, modbus

I'm currently trying to write Wisco protocol (similar to MODBUS ASCII) out to my digital output devices but faced a problem. If I clicked the ON or Off buttons (see the Image [WinForm UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLrJP.jpg)) that already have code to send protocol to my digital output it wouldn't do it.

But in another program where I use a textbox and write the protocol myself then I have to press Enter (If I don't press Enter key it will not work) before clicking send button and it works. What seems to be the problem here?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace WindowsFormsApp4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                serialPort1.PortName = "COM5";
                serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
                serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
                serialPort1.Open();
                progressBar1.Value = 100;
            }

            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.Close();
                progressBar1.Value = 0;
            }
        }

        private void btnOn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Write("#00WDO1,1");
        }

        private void btnOff_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Write("#00WDO1,0");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is serialPort1? I do not see it defined anywhere. Maybe you have to Flush?
without knowing what serialPort1 is exactly I can only guess.
Are you sure the methods are called as you think they are? (set a breakpoint) maybe you didn't add them correctly

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I just have to add `\r\n` to solve this problem.

```cs
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
    {
        serialPort1.Write("#00WDO1,1");
        serialPort1.Write("\r\n");
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
    {
        serialPort1.Write("#00WDO1,0");
        serialPort1.Write("\r\n");
    }
}
```